# Find isomorphisms between two small finite groups $G, H$ of equal cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

> Let $G=\{2,4,8,10,14,16\}\pmod{18}$ and $H=\{3,6,9,12,15,18\}\pmod{21}.$

Show that, under integer multiplication mod $18$ and mod $21$ respectively, each of these forms a group.

Establish isomorphism $between the two groups, and

Find the number of isomorphisms possible from set $G\to H$.

Need check if the two are groups by checking the property of Closure and inverse.

Inverse candidate for
$G=\{2,4,8,10,14,16\}\pmod{18}=\{ 14,16,8,10,2,4\}=G$,

with identity $e=10$.
$2^{-1}=14, 4^{-1}= 16, 8^{-1}=8, 10^{-1}= 10, 14^{-1}=2, 16^{-1}= 4.$

Inverse candidate for
$H=\{3,6,9,12,15,18\}\pmod{21}=\{ 12,6,18,3,15,9\}= H$,

with identity $e=15$.
$3^{-1}=12, 6^{-1}= 6, 9^{-1}=18, 12^{-1}= 3, 15^{-1}=15, 18^{-1}= 9.$

---

Need find order of each element to find mapping under $H\mapsto G$.

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
g & 3&6& 9& 12&15& 18\\ \hline
\varphi(g) &&8 & &&10 &\\\hline
\end{array}

Seems all elements except two in each group have order $=6$ in each group.

First one is identity.

In $G $, $|8|=2$ and in $H$ have $|6|=2.$

$\langle 2\rangle =\{2, 4,8,16, 14, 10\},$ same for others too.

$\langle 4\rangle =\{4, 16, 10, 8, 14\}.$

$\langle 8\rangle =\{8, 10\},$

$\langle 14\rangle =\{14, 16, 8, 4, 2,10 \},$

Identity has order$=1$. Say in group $G$, have: $10, 100\equiv 10\pmod {18}$.

Confused.

---

For last part, have no idea, except that $4$ non-identity elements in each set can map to $4$ such in the other set. So, $16$ Isomorphisms.

What should be table entries in part (b)?

Comment: Hint: both groups are cyclic.

Comment: @David But, group order is not prime number.

Comment: That means not all maps will be isomorphisms.  They have to preserve the order of the elements.  Specifically, an element of order $6$ must map to an element of order $6$.

Comment: But, then $25$ is correct.

Comment: "All elements except identity have order $6$" - not true.

Comment: @David Why ? $\langle 2\rangle =\{2, 4,8,16, 14, 10\}$, same for others too.

Comment: $\langle4\rangle$?

Comment: Just a note... I think $3 \times 6 \equiv 18 (\bmod 21)$, in your second multiplication table.  Also, 4 only generates 3 elements.  Remember, $|<4>|$ must divide the order of the group.

Comment: @MattGroff Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Your question has me curious, too.  I think I figured out what @David is getting at.

Comment: @MattGroff What's that, am curious too as don't know.

Comment: I don't want to spoil things too much, but consider the order of the groups.  If I'm not mistaken, $||<x>||$ must divide the order of the group, for all generators $x$.  So figure out which elements in each group have the same order.  For example, $<2>$ has order 6,  $<8>$ has order 2, etc.  So maybe match up the orders of the groups?  Like, what element has order 2 modulo 21?  Match this up with 8.

Comment: @MattGroff Have given above already (edited, but much before) as $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $G$ and $H$ are cyclic groups with order $6$

For $G$, $e=10$, $G=\langle 2\rangle$, $~~~2^1=2,~2^2=4,~2^3=8,~2^4=16,~2^5=14,~2^6=10=e$

For $H$, $e=15$, $H=\langle 3\rangle$, $~~~3^1=3,~3^2=9,~3^3=6,~3^4=18,~3^5=12,~3^6=15=e$

Isomorphism: $\phi(2^k)=3^k$

Since finite cyclic group with order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$, both $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

For cyclic group, the isomorphism has to map the generator to generator, so consider how many generators in the group.

For $\mathbb{Z}_6$, there are two generators, which are $1$ and $5$, so there are two isomorphisms.

Comment: But, a single table is shown in question. So, how to accomodate both.

Comment: but what? @jiten

Comment: You mean that in each group there are two generators $G: 2, 16; H: 3, 18$. Now, four out of six places are fixed: $18\mapsto 2/16, 3\mapsto 16/2, 6\mapsto 8, 15\mapsto 10.$ Left are elements in $G: 8,10$,  $H: 14, 12.$ How to map these two in each- to each other; in any single way (as generators, two in each group)?

Comment: No, your generator is incorrect. For G, it is 2 and 14, for H, it is 3 and 12. Once the map: generator $\to$ generator, is fixed, then everything is fixed. @jiten

Comment: Yes, missed two order $3$ elements: $16, 4, 10$, similarly for $18, 9, 15$. But, can your refer some source, or can I ping later here. Very nice, as fixing generators in an even order cyclic group followed the same principles as in $\mathbb{Z_6}$!

Comment: But, have choice in terms of where to map either generator in $G$ to the two in $H$. Once fix that, have fixed the map.

Comment: so you have two choices, so you got two isomorphisms as the answer in part (c) @jiten

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137944/discussion-between-jiten-and-mathfail).

Comment: Kindly help with another (related) post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497807/424260.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are six elements in each underlying set and $6=2\times 3$, we can use the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $p$ be an odd prime. Then each group of order $2p$ is isomorphic to either $\Bbb Z_{2p}$ or $D_p$.

*For a proof, see **Theorem 7.3** of Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.*

Only one of $\Bbb Z_6$ and $D_3$ is abelian, and multiplication is commutative; therefore, if they are groups, we must have $G\cong \Bbb Z_6\cong H$.

But by inspection of the multiplication tables, we have

$$\begin{align}
2^1&=2,\\
2^2&=4,\\
2^3&=8,\\
2^4&=16,\\
2^5&=16\times 2=32\equiv 14,\\
2^6&=2^5\times 2\equiv 14\times 2=28\equiv 10,
\end{align}$$

and $10$ is the identity; thus $G\cong\langle 2\rangle$.

Similarly, $H\cong \langle 3\rangle$ with identity $15$.

Isomorphisms of cyclic groups always send generators to generators; thus

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: G&\to H,\\
2&\mapsto 3
\end{align}$$

defines the isomorphism $\varphi(2^n)=3^n.$

The abstract group $\Bbb Z_6\cong\langle a\mid a^6\rangle$ has automorphism group $\Bbb Z_2$, which we can see as $a$ and $a^5$ are generators, again sent to generators, meaning there are **two isomorphisms** between $G$ and $H$. Can you write them explicitly?

> We have $\varphi$ above and the isomorphism given by $$\begin{align} \theta: G&\to H,\\ 2&\mapsto 3^5\equiv 12. \end{align}$$

Comment: So, mapping choice available to non-generator elements doesn't matter. There are two order $3$ elements in both groups.

Comment: Where the nongenerators are sent, @jiten, is determined by where the generators are sent; for example, $$\varphi(4)=\varphi(2\times 2)=\varphi(2)\varphi(2)=3\times 3=9.$$