# Find pair of product of four groups that has the same order, but not isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Find a set of $16$-element product of four groups that have same number of elements of each order, but are not isomorphic.

Choices to form two equal order products of four groups:
$C_1, C_2, C_4, C_8, C_{16}, Q_8.$

---

Need find products of four groups, and to form such two products having equal order, but not isomorphic.

Le, the first product of four groups be denoted by $G= a\times b\times c\times d$, and the second by $H= e\times f\times g\times h.$

The choice need to show equal order, while failing at Isomorphism.

So, $G_1= C_{16}\times C_1\times C_1\times C_1$, and $H= C_8\times C_8\times C_1\times C_1$ will not help; as then will have equal orders as well as Isomorphism too.

A possible choice is :
$G_1= C_{8}\times C_1\times C_1\times C_1$, and $H= Q_8\times C_1\times C_1\times C_1$

Another choice:
$G_1= C_{16}\times C_1\times C_1\times C_1$, and $H= Q_8\times C_8\times C_1\times C_1$

*But, the answer key states: On writing group product, in decreasing group order, have only one choice for determining $G,H$ of order $16$.*

There should be many choices possible, as not specified to use a group only one time in product. Seems it is implicit to use a group only one time in a product.

[cancel]{Edit:. One possible answer is $$G: Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1,$$ $$ H: C_{16}\times C_4\times C_2\times C_1,$$ both of order $|G|=|H|=16.$
But, there should be many choices possible, unless each group can be used once in a product.}[/cancel]

Final Edit: Seems with restriction on both product groups having the same number of elements order-wise, it is impossible to state even the factors of each product.
Getting two products (or, even one ), of length $16$ from given set of values is impossible.

Comment: @LostinSpace is $(16,4)=1$? If not, why not $|H|= 16$?

Comment: Can you explain what is $G'$ here, seems you have taken $G= 16$, $G'=4$. Is it complement of group? Or what?

Comment: Ok. $|H|=|C_{16}|×|C_4|×|C_2|×|C_1|=16×4×2×1=? $

Comment: But, what is $G'$, the meaning of $'$? Also, you have not edited your answer yet to specify this rule.

Comment: $G, G'$ two arbitrary groups and $G×G'$ is the external direct product. The order of $G×G'$ is the product of the order of $G$ and $G'$ .

Comment: So, your condition 2 for $C_m\times C_n\cong C_{mn}$ wrong as it applies for $(16,4)=4\ne 1$?

Comment: So what?  $(16, 4) =4\neq 1$ implies $C_{16}×C_4\ncong C_{64}$

Comment: Great, then the last answer given by @NickyHeckster in comment as: $ G: C_4\times C_4\times C_1\times C_1, H:Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$ is correct. But, is it unique too, if order needed is $16$? Is it unique even when order is not restricted to $16$?

Comment: Yes. $G$ is abelian but $H$ is non abelian and both have order $16$ .

Comment: You have answered one part only. Please answer the unique product part too - for both cases : order of product restricted to $16$, and not restricted to $16$.

Comment: @LostinSpace Sorry, please see the edited correct question. Both products have same number of elements of each order. Also, explicit is restriction of $16$ element product group.  Now, all work done is not applicable, as need same # of elements of each order.

Comment: @LostinSpace It is difficult to guess even what the components groups would be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137976/discussion-between-jiten-and-lost-in-space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So,$ G_1=C_{16}×C_1×C_1×C_1$ and $H=C_8×C_8×C_1×C_1 $will not help; as
> then will have equal orders as well as Isomorphism too.

Both groups neither have the equal order nor they are  isomorphic. $G_1$ has an element of order $16$ but the largest order of an element of $H$ is $8$ . In fact $G_1\cong C_{16}$ and $H\cong C_8×C_8$

( one is cyclic but other is not!)

Key results:

1. $G×G'$ is abelian iff $G, G'$ both are abelian.
2. $C_m ×C_n\cong C_{mn}$ iff $(m, n) =1$
3. $C_8\ncong Q_8$

---

Now you can produce required example.

$G=C_2×C_4×C_8×C_{16}$

$H=C_2×C_4×Q_8×C_{16}$

They are not isomorphic any more as $H$ is non abelian but $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Are they of order $16$ ( as per hint)? Kindly state their respective orders too.

Comment: So, what's the correct answer? Is $G: Q_8\times C_4\times C_2\times C_1, H: C_{16}\times C_4\times C_2\times C_1$ fine?  Here, both $G,H$ are of order $16$.

Comment: No $G$  has order $64$ but $H$ has order $128$

Comment: What if my example is changed to: $G: Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$?

Comment: $|G×G'|=|G|\cdot|G'|$

Comment: Please clarify if stating in context of your answer or my example.

Comment: So, mine failed with $G: Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1, H:  C_{16}\times C_4\times C_2\times C_1.$

Comment: Yes in your example if $G: Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$ , then $G$ , $H=C_8×C_2×C_1×C_1$ have the same order but non isomorphic as $G$ is non abelian but $H$ abelian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137949/discussion-between-jiten-and-lost-in-space).

Answer (score 2):

How about $C_2 \times C_4 \times C_8 \times C_{16}$ and $C_2 \times C_4 \times Q_8 \times C_{16}$? The first group is abelian, the second is not.

Comment: But, is this the only choice possible to show failure? Also, the hint shown is corrected to show product groups are of order $16$.

Comment: OK, then you can take $C_1 \times C_1 \times C_4 \times C_4$, which is abelian of order $16$ and  $C_1 \times C_1 \times C_2 \times Q_8$, which is non-abelian of order $16$.

Comment: But, why $C_4\times C_4$ yields group of order $16$? I thought this multiplication of order applies, for two cyclic groups, if their orders are co-prime. But, here both are the same group.

Comment: Sorry, please see the edited correct question. Both products have same number of elements of each order. Also, explicit is restriction of $16$ element product group.  Now, all work done is not applicable, as need same # of elements of each order.