# Finding order of elements order-wise in product of groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

This is in continuation of earlier [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4497807/424260). Though still not found two such $16$-length product groups, still want to learn the process of finding correct pair of such product groups.

Goal is to show that two $16$- length groups formed by four groups' products, are not isomorphic; though they have same number of elements order-wise.

Let, $G= C_{8}\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$, and $H= Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$

First, need to know if both $G,H$ have $16$- length products.

Next, need show two products $G,H$ have the same number of elements order-wise.

Last part is to show these two groups are not isomorphic, i.e. $G\ncong H.$

Request inputs for first part, as assume that $C_1$ has only identity element that does not add to length of group product.

For second part, my attempt:

So, Cartesian product need be formed

$G$ has components $C_8, C_2, C_1.$

Number of elements of order $8$ in $C_8=2,$ given by $r, r^7,$
Number of elements of order $4$ in $C_8=2,$ given by $r^2, r^6,$
Number of elements of order $2$ in $C_8=1,$ given by $r^3,$
Number of elements of order $1$ in $C_8=1,$ given by $r^0=e.$

Second consider $C_4$:
Number of elements of order $4$ in $C_4=2$ given by $r_4, r_4^3,$
Number of elements of order $2$ in $C_4=1,$ given by $r_4^2,$
Number of elements of order $1$ in $C_8=1,$ given by $r_4^0=e.$

Now, form Cartesian product of two groups : $$C_8=\{e_{C_8}, r_{C_8}, r_{C_8}^2, r_{C_8}^3, r_{C_8}^4, r_{C_8}^5, r_{C_8}^6, r_{C_8}^7\},$$
$$C_4:\{e_{C_4}, r_{C_4}, r_{C_4}^2, r_{C_4}^3, $$
$$CP_{C_8\times C_4}= \{(r_{C_8}^0, r_{C_4}^0), (r_{C_8}^0, r_{C_4}^1), ..., (r_{C_8}^7, r_{C_4}^3) \}$$

But $e$ can pair only with other $e$.

So, get :

$$CP_{C_8\times C_4}= \{(r_{C_8}^0=e_{C_8}, r_{C_4}^0=e_{C_4}), (r_{C_8}, r_{C_4}),  (r_{C_8}^1, r_{C_4}^2),
(r_{C_8}^1, r_{C_4}^3), $$
$$(r_{C_8}^2, r_{C_4}),
(r_{C_8}^2, r_{C_4}^2),
(r_{C_8}^2, r_{C_4}^3),$$
$$(r_{C_8}^3, r_{C_4}),
(r_{C_8}^3, r_{C_4}^2),
(r_{C_8}^3, r_{C_4}^3),
 ... \}$$
Or, a total of ($3\times 7+1= 22$) elements in the Cartesian product.

But, need know order of these elements pair-wise.

Seems a long exercise, is there a shortcut?

For last part, think if above is correct, then can use the property that $C_8\ncong Q_8$.

Comment: For the last part note that $A\ncong B$ might imply $A\times C \cong B\times C$. Take $A=1$, $B=\mathbb{Z}$ and $C=\oplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}_i$.

Comment: One of the groups is abelian, the other is not. This is enough to show they are not isomorphic.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Request to find a pair of product groups of length $16$ as given in linked question at top.

Comment: Just a small note: in English the word we use for the cardinality of the underlying set of a group is "order", not "length". For (finite) groups, "length" means something different (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#Uniqueness:_Jordan%E2%80%93H%C3%B6lder_theorem)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk    It is in question, don't want to change wording given there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct product of two abelian groups is abelian. Thus

$$G= C_{8}\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$$

is abelian. However, since $Q_8$ is nonabelian, $Q_8\times A$ is nonabelian for any group $A$. Thus

$$H= Q_8\times C_2\times C_1\times C_1$$

is nonabelian.

For any groups $K$ and $L$ with $K\cong L$, we have that $K$ is abelian if and only if $L$ is abelian.

Thus the groups $G$ and $H$ cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: My post is wrong as there should be $32$ elements, not $22$. Should I edit it then; or post a new one - that also covers link. There can check all possible combinations of four groups forming product of order $16$ and if find some pair(s), then check if the two products are isomorphic or not. Editing here will still need another post, as need to find pair(s) first , then checking. Else all planned in new post, is done here.

Comment: The same argument should hold for the $32$ case, @jiten.

Comment: Also, @jiten, I have answered the question as it was asķed; if you intended something else, then please start a new post. However, like I said above, the argument should transfer nicely, so instead of editing this one or starting a new post, first try generalising this answer.

Comment: Also, here, $G$ and $H$ have order $16$.